# trigger acts weird if field is not set on INSERT

Tags: mysql, triggers, innodb

here is my trigger

```
        CREATE TRIGGER  before_insert_user_credit
          BEFORE INSERT
          ON user_credit
          FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
             UPDATE profiles SET credit  = credit + NEW.amount  WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id ;
        END
```

its pretty simple and works fine 
i did a insert on `user_credit` by mistake i forgot to set the value for `amount`  ... that filed is integer so the value was stored as default which is 0

so i had 1000 in my `profiles.credit` so i thought it wouldnt change it

1000+0 = 1000

but `profiles.credit`was changed to 0 as well

why is that and how can i prevent this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is BEFORE insert, the omitted NEW.amount is probably NULL. `some_number + null` is null, so credit is probably a non-nullable numeric field that gets assigned it's default value of 0 when you try to update it to null.

Try `... SET credit = credit + IFNULL(NEW.amount, 0) ...` instead.

Comment: makes sense .. is there any way to prevent this from inside the profiles table  ? bcuz lots of other triggers update the same profiles.credit and its much easier to do it once

Comment: Maybe a _before update_ trigger on profiles could be used to ignore updates that try to set credit to null would do the trick (since it seems most such updates would come from trying to add 0 anyway); but that would affect all updates to the table, not just the triggers updating it, so you would have to determine it caused no other problems.